# Phantom project in an Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to put all the projects in the combo, but I get "**External Plugin Libraries**" as shown in the picture below. How am I getting this as project which I don't have. How do I get rid of it?

[image: wrong projects in plugin]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/images/plugin-error1.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [FAQ page "How do I find a particular class from an Eclipse plug-in?"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_a_particular_class_from_an_Eclipse_plug-in%3F),
External Plug-in Libraries is a project automatically created in your workspace, which will:

- have all the Eclipse plug-ins you selected on its build path,
- ensure that they will be consulted by the Java search engine when searching for and opening Java types.

That means you have the RCP edition where a workspace is already set up so that all Eclipse plug-ins are found by the Java search engine.
The manual way to do this is:

> - Activate the 'Plug-ins' view by going to Window > Show View > Other > PDE > Plug-ins.
> - Select all plug-ins in the view.
> - From the context menu, select Add to Java Search.

As of Eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede) the External Plug-in Libraries Java project is hidden by default (see [bug 194694](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=194694)).
Use the Java element filters dialog to include the External Plug-in Libraries project in the Package Explorer view.

Comment: Is there any way to filter this out as this is a binary project?

Comment: @javaguy: maybe by creating a new workspace in which you reference only your project, not adding any PDE plugin to the Java search.