# how to resolve org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException

Tags: exception, java, runtimeexception

I never encountered this exception before

```
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource '/External Plug-in Libraries' is not open.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.checkAccessible(Project.java:137)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.isNatureEnabled(Project.java:817)
at newmodulewizrd.ui.Integrate.printProjectInfo(Integrate.java:130)
at newmodulewizrd.ui.Integrate.getWorkSpace(Integrate.java:123)
at newmodulewizrd.ui.Integrate.presentOptionsAndAddToMain(Integrate.java:117)
at newmodulewizrd.ui.Integrate$2.actionPerformed(Integrate.java:84)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
```

this is my code

```
try {
  if (project.isNatureEnabled("org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature")) {
    IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
      if(flag2==0) {
        printPackageInfos(javaProject);
        flag2=1;
      } else {
        IPackageFragmentRoot srcFolder = cm.createNewSourceFolder(project);
        newModule = srcFolder.createPackageFragment(textfield.getText(), true,null);
        printPackageInfos(javaProject);
        try {
          cm.refreshWorkspace();
        } catch (CoreException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
   } else {
     System.out.println("something went wrong here");
   }
 } catch (CoreException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

*I suspect it is trying to access my 'jre system library [jre6] folder {below my src folder}' inside my java project*

**Any idea on how to resolve it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found solution to problem so m posting it here so that anyone with same problem can benefit

apparently there was a link to a "phantom project" as mentioned here

[Phantom project in an Eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887994/phantom-project-in-an-eclipse-plugin)

so i followed the steps

```
1. Activate the 'Plug-ins' view by going to Window > Show View > Other > PDE > Plug-ins.

2. Select all plug-ins in the view.
```

and restarted my IDE. my "External Plug-in Libraries Java project" was visible now. i deleted this project and now everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when text searching into my workspace. It started happening after importing a new C++ library project from GIT into my Eclipse CDT project list.

I removed the directory below to fix this. It seems like it was corrupted and it was containing a link to an old deleted file that couldn't be found when text searching.

- C:\Users\me\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources